# Why is Tiles used along with Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, thymeleaf

I'm searching for a Spring WebFlow, Thymeleaf example without Apache Tiles. 
In my opinion, I think it is not necessary to use Tiles, because with Thymeleaf it is possible to create Templates.

This is a very good example, but it uses Tiles. Can anybody tell me why Tiles is used in this example?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/webflow-showcase

Comment: Why not? The example is about `web-flow`, not `Tiles`. You can use whatever technique you like as UI template.

Comment: It is not necessary to use Tiles with thymeleaf. I don't like Tiles and I am working on a project with thymeleaf and without Tiles. I am using the Layout feature of thymeleaf and it is working as I expected.

Comment: Thymeleaf is a low level template mechanism like JSP but better.  Tiles is a higher level template mechanism that can be used component based (this means Tiles fragments can be recursively nestable) which is well suited for JSF.